# linux - how to get a stack trace when a memory address is written to

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, hardware

I have a memory corruption in my c/c++ program which causes a segfault. this was reproduced a few times and the same address gets corrupted every time.

Is there any way I can call a function when this address is written to? I tried using hwbp_lib https://github.com/hawkinsw/hwbp_lib , but my callback doesn't get called when I write to the requested memory address after setting the breakpoint.

I am running on an x86 intel.

Comment: Does your debugger support watchpoints?

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. I do this all the time. Set a watchpoint in gdb, wait for it to get tripped. Get a stacktrace. Problem solved. Do you know how to use gdb?

Comment: I know how to use gdb, and this was indeed my initial direction but my system's high availability components kill my process if it remains unresponsive for too long so I can't use it.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but that's how this is done. In order to effectively develop a complicated application it is necessary to have a useful development environment, with a debugger, and without any other constraints or limitations on its use.

Comment: you are right of course, and we have it. the problem is that the bug is reproduced only on full system deployments which also run the HA elements.

Comment: and according to what I read around this should be doable by using ptrace, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried to enable Address Sanitizer? As that is non-interactive and it should report any memory mangling issues. Some hints how to use ASAN I wrote in: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/05/05/memory-error-checking-in-c-and-c-comparing-sanitizers-and-valgrind

Comment: also a direction I considered and will probably take if I have no other choice. I have 2 problems with this approach: 1. I am not sure the system can handle the performance hit from asan and 2. I am afraid it will alert on many other problems before reaching the real one.